# Refactor my MVC application to use areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, refactoring

I have MVC application that I wrote that have this structure(regular MVC with Devexpress themes):

[image: My app sturcture]

Now new developers want to add code to my MVC app **that not related to my code** just like another application in my site, so I thought just that I would give every developer new area and there he will write his code.
and that way my code and the other developer will not mess up.
I have two questions:

1. Do it make sense?
2. Should I move also my code to new area?

by the way right now I don't have areas at all so I will be glad to know if there are special steps to do when I add new areas and maybe I want that the _Layout of all the areas will be the same ( can I do it without code duplication?

Comment: Are there any strong reason for not to create a new project within the solution?

Comment: Yes because the boss want only one website that have couple of applications.... if you think it is problem to make what I described I will be glad to hear why... maybe it is really not make sense

Comment: It is not a problem, but only inconvenient as I see it. What if the new implementation is really bad and behaves in a way that make the applicationpool recycle. Then your application will be affected by the same recycle. That would not have happened with separate applications running their own applicationpool. If they need to use some backend components, consider making them available through shared projects.

Comment: From the information you provided, I'd also tend to suggest a new project/app. If you can't do that, add a test project. Make sure your code is all covered with good unit tests. Then let them loose, and make sure they don't cause any tests to fail.

Comment: I can't understand, if the new developers develop from thier own area how can they change my code they write standalone app that uses my model and web services and I from my home page add link to thier application. am I wrong?